# Image view appears for a few seconds then screen goes white

Tags: ios

If using the latest Xcode 7 (Xcode 7 GM seed) I perform these steps:

```
1) Create new project / single view application
2) Disable size classes
3) In the storyboard add an image view as a child of the main view
4) In the storyboard provide an image for the image view
5) Run on a device with iOS 9
```

When the app launches the image is displayed for about 2 seconds, then the view goes white.

What's going on? I literally have done nothing other than the 5 steps above. Why is the image initially appearing then disappearing.

This is 100% repeatable, I can create any new project, add a image view, same effect.
Bug with Xcode, iOS 9? Surely this would have been noticed by now, 7 & 9 are both advanced now. What else then?

[And for any overzealous jobsworths out there, no I don't have any code to post, I haven't written any, its all boilerplate]

Comment: What does it do on iOS8 with Xcode 6?

Comment: Its fine with that combination

Comment: is this happening on simulator ? , i recommend to test on device & try with xcode 6

Comment: @Mohamad. Read step 5 again

Comment: @MartinH sry , i think this is bug !! but it's creep!

Comment: I'm curious. I'll try to investigate tomorrow if no one found the reason.

Comment: I just tried it on a device with iOS 8.4 and it was the same result. Implying its an issue with Xcode GM Seed. Currently downloading XCode 7.1 to see what happens with that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

When you create a template project with Xcode 7 in addition to the Main.storyboard file there is also a LaunchScreen.storyboard file created.

I didn't realize -  I just saw the .storyboard extension and didn't see that there were two.

So what I was actually doing was adding the image view to the LaunchScreen.storyboard and not to the Main.storyboard.

Doh.